# Why doesn't max-priority queue have DECREASE-KEY?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the discussion of heap data structure, for example in [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), the max-priority queue only needs INSERT, MAXIMUM, EXTRACT-MAX, and INCREASE-KEY. But why doesn't it also have DECREASE-KEY, at the least, its operation will also invalidate the heap property? Is it practically unimportant?

Comment: I would think this is related to how min-priority queues don't usually have INCREASE-KEY, even though it is a perfectly well-defined operation.  My guess is that this is just something that doesn't arise much.  Also, w00t on getting exactly 1337 reputation!

Comment: I could swear I asked this exact question before but I can't find it.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/increase-key-and-decrease-key-in-a-binary-min-heap

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is stopping you to implement DECREASE-KEY in your binary heap. It can be done in O(log N) without breaking any invariants.

My guess is that it isn't included, because it's not needed very often.

Comment: what is your pseudo code to implement this? Just heapify at current location?

Comment: Assuming “heapify” means moving the current node down until the heap invariants are satisfied, then yeah.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a MAX-HEAP, DECREASE-KEY will be MAX-HEAPIFY in section 6.2 "Maintaining the heap property" of CLRS, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW my CLR V1 talks about INSERT, MIN, EXTRACT-MIN, UNION, DECREASE-KEY, and DELETE, but we can convert to your version by flipping signs.

I think this set is driven by the requirements of the algorithms that use priority queues, such as minimum spanning tree, Dijstra shortest path, and (I suspect) A*. For instance, if you look at the start of the chapter on minimum spanning trees, you can see a note that Prim's algorithm can be sped up if you replace binary heaps with fibonacci heaps.

Comment: "my CLR V1"? Can you explain please? Exactly, what I was asking actually corresponds to "Why doesn't min-priority queue have INCREASE-KEY?"

Comment: "my CLR v1" refers to the first edition of the book, which did not have Stein as an author. The second paragraph answers your question, though: the algorithms that use priority queues only need to be able to move entries earlier in the queue, not later.